# Margin/Padding Shrinks ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, margin, padding, android-relativelayout

I recently tried to position an imageview's x and y coordinates with no luck, it seems there is no way to do it in Gingerbread. I then decided to try out paddings and margins, but when I set them, it shrinks my imageview. I set a left padding of 250dp and image view became tiny. The layout_height and width are set to wrap_content. I'm not sure what's going on. Does anyone know why setting a padding/margin would shrink an imageview?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're confusing margin and padding. Margin is the area outside of your view, while padding affects the content *inside* your margin.

[image: Margins and Padding Example]

If you set padding, then it is going to affect your available content area, and assuming you have a ScaleType set, it's going to shrink your image down to fit the available space.

Now, you say you've tried margins, but margins will do exactly what you're asking.

For example, if you wanted an `ImageView` placed `10dp` from the top-left corner, you can do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image_id"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Keep in mind that this places it `10dp` with respect to the `parent` boundaries. If your parent layout also has padding, then that will affect your content placement.

Comment: Ah, Thanks so much! I wish Gingerbread had the new setX and Y methods though :/

Answer (score 1):

if by shrink you mean the picture's ratio is messed then you should use

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

this will prevent the ratio from changing

Comment: yep up for this one, if you mean your image inside imageview is padded it will indeed shrink, but if you want your image to be centered in an imageview you should do this suggestion